# Append child nodes to a list of empty nodes. (Getting out of memory exception)

Tags: c#, linq

I have an xml similar to this:

```
<root>
   <car name="Honda">
    <part name="part1" />
    <part name="part2" />
    <part name="part3" />
   </car>
   <car name="Ford" />
   <car name="Subaru" />
   <car name="VW" />
   <car name="Chevy">
    <part name="part5" />
    <part name="part6" />
    <part name="part7" />
   </car>
   <car name="BMW" />
</root>
```

What I want to do is update any car node that has no parts and add the same parts that Honda has. ("Chevy" in this example should not be updated)

I am getting an out of memory exception in my code.

My code looks similar to:

```
   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\MyFile.xml", true))
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(sr);

    var allCars = xDoc.Descendants("root").Descendants().ToList();

    var carToUse = allCars.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Honda").FirstOrDefault();
    var listCars = carToUse.Descendants("car").ToList();

    var fullCars = allCars.Where(x => x.Descendants("part").Any()).ToList();
    var emptyPermissions = allCars.Where(x => x.Descendants("part").Any() == false).ToList();

    foreach (var perm in emptyPermissions)
    {
        perm.Add(listCars);
    }
}
```

Now in my actual data file I have around 600 empty nodes that I want to append 10 children nodes to.

I shouldn't be getting an out of memory exception for that.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: `xDoc.Descendants("root").Descendants()` means all descendants (including parts) make it `xDoc.Descendants("root").Elements()`. I don't know if that will fix anything but first fix your code. Your `listCars` variable is empty with your example too... debug before asking questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost identical to Ankit's answer:

```
    private void DoIt()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\XMLStuff_42582050\XMLStuff_42582050\sample.xml", true))
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(sr);//load your xml
            var allCars = xDoc.Root.Elements("car");//get a list of all the cars
            var carToUse = allCars.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Honda").FirstOrDefault();//pick the one car to use
            var hondaParts = carToUse.Descendants("part");//get the parts of the car to use
            var carswithNoparts = allCars.Where(x => x.HasElements == false).ToList();//get all the cars with no parts
            foreach (var car in carswithNoparts)//iterate through the cars with no parts
            {
                car.Add(hondaParts);//add the honda parts
            }
            xDoc.Save(@"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\XMLStuff_42582050\XMLStuff_42582050\out.xml");//save output
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is exactly identical to mine.

Comment: @Ankit its essentially the same, though I listed the cars with no parts slightly differently. `var carswithNoparts = allCars.Where(x => x.HasElements == false).ToList();`, and some variable names are more representative of what they host. Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 1):

one issue with your listcars as it will not give you exact empty cars.
try this code it is working.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\myfile.xml", true))
        {
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(sr);

            var allCars = xDoc.Root.Elements();

            var carToUse = allCars.Where(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Honda").FirstOrDefault();
            var listCars = carToUse.Descendants("part").ToList();

            var fullCars = allCars.Where(x => x.Descendants("part").Any()).ToList();
            var emptyPermissions = allCars.Where(x => x.Descendants("part").Any() == false).ToList();

            foreach (var perm in emptyPermissions)
            {
                perm.Add(listCars);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is no more then I said in the comments